# Mantener datos de la vista de fragments en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto que se basa en un pequeño y simple escape room, pero me encuentro con un problema que me está dando dolor de cabeza.

Mi aplicación tiene 2 fragments, que su xml(fragment 1) tiene dos botones, si hago click en boton 1 se hace visible otro boton 2 que está en el mismo xml design.

El problema: Si cambio al fragment 2 y vuelvo al fragment 1. Todo vuelve a empezar...El boton 2 vuelve a ser invisible.

¿ Como puedo mantener los eventos hechos en el fragment 1, si he cambiado al fragmento 2 y regreso al fragment 1 de nuevo ?

He probado con :

 `fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_nav_game, z2).addToBackStack(null).commit();`
No funciona dejándolo en la pila.
y tampoco con esto : `fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_nav_game, z2).addToBackStack(null).commit();`
Que hace que se reemplace el fragment por ese nuevo, naturalmente llamando de nuevo a onCreateView

¿ Alguna ayuda por favor ? Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Pero todo apunta a que en el fondo hay una mala o nula implementación de los [Componentes de Arquitectura de Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture). Por ejemplo, ¿por qué necesitas dos fragmentos para esto? Y, si usas Room, se supone que los cambios operados en el primer fragmento serían registrados en la BD y cuando pasas al otro fragmento deberías ir a buscarlos allí para mostrarlos en el nuevo fragmento. En todo caso, ¿no es mejor observar/actualizar todo desde el mismo sitio, que es lo que justifica cambiar?

Comment: Son pantallas diferentes, en un fragmento haces unas acciones y en el otro fragmento haces otras, con lo que en el fragmento 1 si has realizado la acción, podras avanzar en el fragmento 2 con lo que si en el fragmento 2 tiene el objeto puedes volver al fragment 1 y seguir avanzando. Con eso me deja que si yo vuelvo al fragment 1 despues de estar en el fragment 2... Fragment 1 desaparece las acciones ( eventos ) que haya realizado.. por eso necesito mantener las acciones que he hecho mientras navego entre fragments.